# How can i create a makefile for multiple targets, each having the same identifier in the output, as inputs?

Tags: makefile

i have a list of input*.in files, and for each of them i want to generate an output*.out file using make.

```
target1.out : input1.in
    {external program} < input1.in > target1.out
```

I have 0 experience with gnu make, so would much appreciate help
How should i do it best using makefile?

Comment: Take a look at [static pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
target%.out: input%.in
    {external program} < $< >$@
```

Now `make` knows how to generate `targetXX.out` from `inputXX.in`. You still have to add an actual target, either on the command line (like `make targetShirley.out` assuming you have `inputShirley.in`) or in a separate recipe. A common arrangement is to have

```
sources := $(wildcard input*.in)
targets := $(patsubst input%.in,target%.out,$(sources))

.PHONY: all
all: $(targets)
```

(typically at the top of the `Makefile`) and then `make all` will produce all the files it can.

A common *antipattern* is to write a single recipe with a loop, like

```
everything:
    for file in input*.in; do \
        t=$${file%.in}; \
        t=target$${t#input}.out; \
        {external program} >"$$t"; \
    done
```

(notice also how the shell's dollar signs have to be doubled to prevent `make` from attempting to interpret them). Besides being clumsy, this disables the single crucial reason to use `make` in the first place, namely to avoid creating files which are already up to date.

Comment: The `$(wildcard)` etc functions are specific to GNU Make; there are ways to write this in legacy `make` too but those tend to be somewhat more tortured. If you need instructions for a specific non-GNU `make` then perhaps edit your question to clarify your need.